# django sendgrid send unique arguments

Tags: django, email, sendgrid

Sendgrid allows to specify unique arguments when sending emails. These can be used for the event webhook integration to identify emails [doc](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/unique_arguments.html).

I have an existing code piece in django that uses `django.core.mail.EmailMultiAlternatives` to send emails via SendGrid. I'd like to specify the above mentioned unique arguments if possible. So far I was trying to use the `custom_args` field

```
email.custom_args = {'test_arg': 'value'}
```

but that didn't seem to work.
I saw that there's a django-sendgrid [module](https://github.com/elbuo8/sendgrid-django), but if possible I'd prefer not having to re-write the existing code base.

Comment: did you try to add `headers` dict to the `EmailMultiAlternatives` looks like the `Unique Arguments` is email headers.

Comment: How would I add them as a header?

Comment: [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/email/#emailmessage-objects) example, it is also work for `EmailMultiAlternatives`

Comment: so when I write a header entry with `{'Message-ID': 'xyz'}` then in the event that is returned I receive my message id in the tag `{'smtp-id': 'xyz'}`, why is that??

Comment: i think the `Message-ID` is specific header that override by smtp server

Comment: okay thank you! If you formulate your comments as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't use the SendGrid, but looks like the `Unique Arguments` is email `headers`, and by the doc: [emailmessage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/email/#emailmessage-objects), you can add `headers` for example:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives

subject, from_email, to = 'hello', 'EXAMPLE@FROM.com', 'EXAMPLE@TO.NET'
text_content = 'This is an important message.'
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(
    subject,
    text_content,
    from_email,
    [to], headers={"customerAccountNumber": "55555", },
)
msg.send()
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the [SendGrid Python Library](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python)?

The term `custom_args` is specific to [Web API v3 Mail Send](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/index.html), so adding it to your SMTP message won't work. The Web v3 API call is faster and more full-featured than the SMTP transaction, but is a newer generation of call, and has some updated vocabulary.

If you need to send via SMTP, you'll need to use the term `unique_args` within the [X-SMTPAPI header](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/unique_arguments.html) specifically. That will allow those key:values to be attached to all Events related to the messages generated in that send.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Python and Django to configure sending messages through SendGrid: https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/django

As others have mentioned, the best way to match event webhooks with previously sent emails is to add a unique identifier when sending the email. To do so, you need to use the `X-SMTPAPI` header with a `unique_args` key/value. It's important to configure this header correctly, otherwise the email will be rejected. Two helpful links:

- [Building an X-SMTPAPI Header](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/building-an-x-smtpapi-header#unique-arguments)
- [Unique Arguments](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/tracking-events/event#unique-arguments)

Based on this documentation, here's what my implementation looks like:

```
MESSAGE_ID_KEY = 'jv_message_id'
message = EmailMultiAlternatives(
        subject=subject,
        body=plain_content,
        from_email=from_email or EMAIL_ADDRESS_SEND,
        to=to_emails,
        cc=cc_email,
        headers={
            'X-SMTPAPI': json.dumps({'unique_args': {MESSAGE_ID_KEY: '<internal message id>'}})
        }
    )
```

Then when the webhook is sent, I get the message ID like this:

```
    def post(self, request):
        event_data = request.data
        if not event_data:
            logger.error('Sendgrid webhook delivered an unparseable request')
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            
        for event in event_data:
            event_type = event['event']
            if not (message_id := event.get(MESSAGE_ID_KEY)):
                logger.warning('Sendgrid webhook delivered an event without a unique message ID')
                continue
...
```